# Spring Security - BytesEncryptor - not getting the proper encrypted password

Tags: java, spring, encryption, spring-security, aes

```
BytesEncryptor enc =  Encryptors.standard("encryptionPassword",saltKey);

byte[] encryptedPwd = enc.encrypt(pwd.getBytes());

byte[] decryptedPwd = enc.decrypt(encryptedPwd );
```

I have used BytesEncryptors (Spring security) to encrypt/decrypt the password. I have my encrypted/decrypted passwords in byte[]. I want to get the encrypted/decrypted password.

So what I do is,

```
System.out.println(new String(encryptedPwd,"UTF-8"));

System.out.println(new String(decryptedPwd,"UTF-8"));
```

The second line is working well. The first line doesnt give me the string representation of the encoded password. It shows something unuseful.

1) Why is my first line not working like second one?

2) If I want to use the same encryption algorithm to my spring bean configuration(XML file) how would I do? Like DataSource Info/some other login credentials should be encrypted in XML file.(* I don't use Hibernate here)

Comment: Try to format your code with `Ctrl+'K'` or with ' ` ' quotes

Comment: What do you expect the encrypted password to look like?

Comment: I get something like this ‘–Ú×°ä÷q“ýd. And I am not sure if its an encrypted password to store in properties file

Answer (score 1):

For a text-safe representation of "random" byte array, use base64 encoding:

```
System.out.println(Base64Utils.encodeToString(encryptedPwd));
```

You can both encode and decode with [Base64Utils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Base64Utils.html).

Comment: @user3603360 Nice to hear. Don't forget to accept if you think this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print a byte array to a hexadecimal string.

For example :

- byte 0 => 00
- byte -1 => ff
- byte 127 => 7f
- byte -128 => 80

If you use Spring Security, just use the method `org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex#encode` which returns `char[]`.

In the class `HexEncodingTextEncryptor` you can also find this shortcut :

```
    public String encrypt(String text) {
        return new String(Hex.encode(this.encryptor.encrypt(Utf8.encode(text))));
    }
```